# Spanning a Gap Between House and Garage with Chain Link

Tags: concrete, fence

I bought this house a few years ago and the previous owner decided that this embarrassment was the best addition for this garage.

Needless to say, it's horrendous and I want to take it off. (*and the rest of the garage will be updated as well*) No problem. The overhang is staying. The concrete pad is staying for now too. However, I'll have a gap between the chain link and the actual side of the garage. This is a problem because I have a dog that likes to escape.

My question is; Will I be able to span that space with a section of chain link and attach it to the side of the actual garage *without* having to put in a post?

I really don't want to have to cut through the concrete to put in a post.

[image: Straight-on view]

Comment: I'll just comment, as it's purely speculation, but I would be surprised if you couldn't find a chain link compatible post that has a collar that allows for anchoring to a surface.  Such as with concretes screws or compression anchors.